# Jar bundler not getting main class automatically from jar file. can you please describe the whole process?

Tags: java, macos, .app

I need to wrap jar file in .app file through **jar bundler** in mac os x but whenever I am going to do this ***jar bundler could getting main class from jar*** file but this jar is working well on windows or Linux platform's please give me the link or proper step by step description for wrapping jar file to mac os executable file (**.app**). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a significant reason not to use JWS? Its 1) More portable 2) More maintainable 3) Fully Functional. If you decide for some reason that you ***have*** to bundle the program as a .app, then definitely use [AppBundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) - JarBundler is effectively deprecated.

Comment: Now I am using App bundler as you advice me but this time it is causing an error "taskdef class com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]"

Comment: ppst99 - did you specify the correct classpath for your taskdef?

Comment: lib/appbundler-1.0.jar here my appbundler jar file is located

Comment: Now giving error "Cause : The name is undefined"

Comment: Coding by comments rarely, if ever works. Give it an honest go at solving the issues by researching online, and if run into a specific problem, post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the ant builder with custom build.xml file

command to use ant is.

go to the location of build.xml file through terminal after that hit the command.

```
 $ant yourTargetName
```

Where your target name is declared in you build.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <project name="Project Name" default="default" basedir=".">


    <taskdef name="bundleapp"
     classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"
     classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />



     <target name="bundle-Target Name">
       <bundleapp outputdirectory="."
           name="Your Project Name"
           displayname="yourProjectDisplayName"
           identifier="yourMainClassName"
           shortversion="1.0"
           applicationCategory="public.app-category.developer-tools"
           mainclassname="yourMainClassName">

           <classpath file="/yourJarFileLocation"/>
           <option value="-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>
       </bundleapp>
     </target>
  </project>
```

To wrap in package this .app file.

Hit the command on terminal.

```
 $productbuild --component filename.pkg /your app file location
```